# Upgrading Pimcore from 3.1 to 4.2

Tags: upgrade, pimcore

How can I upgrade Pimcore via admin panel?

Getting this message when upgrading:

```
Status: 502 | Bad Gateway
URL: /admin/update/index/job-parallel
Params:
-> type: download
-> revision: 3805
-> url: https://update.pimcore.org/v2/getFiles.php?for=3805&offset=0&limit=50
Message: 
502 Bad Gateway
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.10.1
```

Debug log is empty.

Comment: Is somebody tried to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Pimcore server has gone away during the update.
You should try to upgrade again, the server does at the moment reply with a 200 Okay status code.

Make sure you backup your system before upgrading. There are no known update issues that I'm aware of that could affect your update.